# Theming CCK node in Drupal 5

Tags: drupal, themes, cck

I need to add a few links to the bottom of node (custom type) form in Drupal 5.

I've tried contemplate module, but it actually deals only with custom fields (contemplate template doesn't contain node title, description, taxonomy fields) - while I need to add links below or above actual body field.

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most useful recipe :

from([Theming CCK Input Form | drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/187239))

Example (to use in themename/template.php file):

```
<?php
function phptemplate_product_node_form($form) {
  global $user;
  $vars = array('user' => $user, 'form' => $form);
  $vars['title'] = drupal_render($form['title']);
  $vars['body'] = drupal_render($form['body_filter']);
  // etc
  return _phptemplate_callback('product_edit', $vars);
}
?>
```